# Amazon EC2 and S3 Price Calculation

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am new to AWS so in case I made mistake in understanding concepts please explain. 
 I have a webapp written in Nodejs and I want to deploy it to aws Elastic Beanstalk which requires an EC2 t2.small (linux) instance and aws S3 to store server files.

Strategy:
**Data Transfer Out** to Internet : Using EC2 to render files from s3
**Data Tranfer In** from Internet: Using S3 HTTPs commands from aws NodeJS SDK

**Question**: Do I have to pay additional for migrating files from S3 to EC2 before rendering it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is very detailed d[ata transfer pricing rules list](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) for EC2 instances.

Data transfer IN to EC2 **FROM internet** is 0.00/GB, which in other words FREE.

Data transfer OUT has costs associated (and in some cases FREE) depending on your setup.

EDIT:

After question edit, still this answer applies. S3 to EC2, no charge. EC2 to outside world has some costs associated.

Comment: I am confused like .. Do we have to pay extra to fetch server and static files from S3 before rendering using EC2 ?

Comment: @SarthakPatidar No, EC2 fetching content from S3 has no cost. But, you will send the html to browser from EC2, that will be charged.

Comment: Which Basically means **Data Out Price of EC2**.... Am I correct this time @kosa ?

Comment: @SarthakPatidar that is correct. It can be ANY data, so your words are correct. ANY DATA OUT of EC2.

Comment: @SarthakPatidar Good luck!